# Jira Integration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, jira

I am very new to this.So pardon me if I make any mistakes.

I am trying to read the Jira database.I just need to read it.

No write operations will be involved.

I am using C#.From what little I know, I think a connection has to be established with the Jira database using

```
SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
```

And then I can read data using SqlReader.I have tried searching through the database and found few links like  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/762516/Connecting-to-Jira-using-Csharp

But I am not being able to understand.Can anyone help me out or direct me to few resources.

In the links that I searched through there are terms like "Rest API" etc. Do I need to know them ?

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Comment: Hi Anant- I am not understanding what code to try and where to paste it.I'm trying to understand the links available online.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "Where to paste it"? How about don't copy/paste code at all. Understand what you're doing and write the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks John.You are very correct.I would love to write it myself.What approach should I follow to understand the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the database, and want to read data that way, that's entirely possible using standard .NET objects, but you'll probably need to be decent at SQL to get the data out that you want.

Here's how you can (try to) access the database:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from whatever_jira_table", conn);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//look up how to read from a reader
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Another option is to use a Jira API which it looks like you can get from NuGet through Visual Studio.  If you go this route, you need access to the Jira REST API, and it will expose a more friendly (different?) way to access data.

Either way, just go into Visual Studio, make a console app, and start adding code and stepping through with the debugger until thing start making sense.

Comment: Hi MStodd..I know my way through C# but the problem is what connection string do I use for authenticated Jira access ?

Comment: @Neha For that, you'd need to talk to whomever is responsible for administering and maintaining your Jira installation.  If you have to talk to someone else about getting access, you might have more luck with getting access to the REST API than directly to the database.  You're looking for database access OR Jira access.  Database creds doesn't mean you'll be able to use the REST API